# regex expected value in a postion depends on a random value in another position

Tags: php, regex

I need regex to find all shortcode tag pairs that look like this `[sc1-g-data]b[/sc1-g-data]` but the number next to the `sc` can vary but they must match.

So something like this won't work `\[sc(.*?)\-((.|\n)*?)\[\/sc(.*?)\-` as this matches unmatching tag pairs like this which i don't want `[sc1-g-data]b[/sc2-g-data]`

so the expected number in the second tag depends on a random number in the first tag

Comment: Use something like `\[(sc\d*-[^\]\[]*)\]([\s\S]*?)\[\/\1\]`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bONWXm/1).

Comment: I think you need back references: https://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html

Comment: So i tried this (php was used)

`$pattern = "/\[sc(.*?)\-((.|\n)*?)\[\/sc\1\-/"; $string = '[sc1-g-data]a[/sc1-g-data] '; preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER); var_dump($matches);` 

but it just returned this
`array(0) { } `

Comment: so i did some fiddeling around and i realised the dashes didnt need escaping?
so this works like a charm `$pattern = "/\[sc(.*?)-((.|\n)*?)\[\/sc\1-/";`

Comment: whoops one more weird thing is that I have to use single quotes not double quotes? so in fact i have to do this `$pattern = '/\[sc(.*?)-((.|\n)*?)\[\/sc\1-/';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a regex like:

```
\[(sc\d*-[^\]\[]*)\]([\s\S]*?)\[\/\1\]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bONWXm/1)

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `(sc\d*-[^\]\[]*)` - Capturing group 1: `sc`, 0+ digits, `-`, and then 0+ chars other than `]` and `[`
- `\]` - a `]` char
- `([\s\S]*?)` - Capturing group 2: any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `\[\/` - a `[/` string
- `\1` - the same text stored in Group 1
- `\]` - a `]` char

See the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5C%5B(sc%5Cd*-%5B%5E%5C%5D%5C%5B%5D*)%5C%5D(%5B%5Cs%5CS%5D*%3F)%5C%5B%5C%2F%5C1%5C%5D):

[image]

[**PHP demo**](https://3v4l.org/09ZCd):

```
$pattern = '~\[(sc\d*-[^][]*)](.*?)\[/\1]~s'; 
$string = '[sc1-g-data]a[/sc1-g-data] '; 
if (preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches)) {
  print_r($matches);
}
```

Mind the use of a single quoted string literal, if you use a double quoted one you will need to use `\\1`, not `\1` as `'\1'` != `"\1"` in PHP.

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => [sc1-g-data]a[/sc1-g-data]
    [1] => sc1-g-data
    [2] => a
)
```

Comment: thanks apologies for not noticing this answers new updates

Answer (score 0):

If your tags are just anything between brackets `[blah][/blah]` you can use:

`\[(.*?)\].*?\[\/\1\]`